# Dynamically adding a new tab to mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular v8 and Angular Materials. In particular mat-tab-group and mat-tab. I want to have something like the below. I want to be able to click on the "+" (which looks like a tab) and the result would be that it would create a new tab

[image]

After clicking on the "+" we'd see as below (focus is on the new tab we just added)

[image]

If I have a button above the mat-tab-group (which adds a new tab) all works fine but we want the "+" to be at the end of the tab list (as shown above). I can get the tab to create but focus doesn't got to it.

My code looks like. In the **setSelectedIndex** method call I add a new customer object and then set the selectedIndex to it. But no joy. Code sample below. Can try add as a plunkr if needs be

```
<mat-tab-group
        class="no-vertical-scroll"
        [disableRipple]="true"
        animationDuration="0ms"
        (selectedTabChange)="setSelectedIndex($event)"
        (focusChange)="onFocusChange($event)"
        [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex"
        style="margin-top: 10px;">

    <mat-tab *ngFor="let customer of customers; let index = index"
             class="fullHeight no-vertical-scroll no-horizontal-scroll">

        <div>
            content for each tab
        </div>

    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab tooltip="New Tab" class="fullHeight no-vertical-scroll" label="New Tab">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label class="fullWidth">
            <span><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></span>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

Thanks Ro

Answer (score 6):

You can try **creating tabs using an array and bind it using ngFor**, Then you can alter the array which will reflect changes into your tabs such as adding and removing.

Check the following example:

```
<div>
      <button mat-raised-button
              class="example-add-tab-button"
              (click)="addTab(selectAfterAdding.checked)">
        Add new tab
      </button>
      <mat-checkbox #selectAfterAdding> Select tab after adding </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    
    <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value"
                   (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)">
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
        Contents for {{tab}} tab
      </mat-tab>

   <mat-tab disabled>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="addTab(selectAfterAdding.checked)">
            <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </ng-template>
   </mat-tab>

    </mat-tab-group>
```

Ts file

```
  tabs = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];
  selected = new FormControl(0);

  addTab(selectAfterAdding: boolean) {
    this.tabs.push('New');

    if (selectAfterAdding) {
      this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.length - 1);
    }
  }

  removeTab(index: number) {
    this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

[stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/epealnoxvlg?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.ts)

**Updated**

you can add a + button located last in the tabs by adding a tab after the array containing the actual tabs as follows:

```
<mat-tab disabled>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="addTab(selectAfterAdding.checked)">
            <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

[image: Add New Tab]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I actually had done exactly what you'd shown but my user wants the add button (well a button with the "+" icon) located at the end of the tabs (i.e. to the right of the last tab) and not above the mat-tab-group. Sorry I should have probably said that in my first post. Ron