# Angular Material - Selecting new tab after adding - Issue when no tab beforehand

Tags: angular, angular-material

*Disclaimer : my question is about a special case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64641614/6640634). I want to create a tab group with a "+" tab in last position, which can create more tabs, **and no initial tab apart from this "+" tab**. [The only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64641881/6640634) to the linked question provides a working stackblitz with three initial tabs, which is not my situation. If I remove those initial tabs, I get the erroneous behaviour described below.*

**The issue :** given that there is no tab at first in the group apart from the "+" tab, if I click this "+" tab, a new tab is indeed created, but the focus remains on the "+" tab instead of jumping on the newly created tab as intended. It goes on with more new tabs. **But** if I create a first tab, select it, and then click on the "+" tab, then the new tabs are selected after creation as intended.

What am I doing wrong here ? What is provoking this seemingly inconsistent behaviour ?

HTML :

```
<div>
  <span class="example-input-label"> Selected tab index: </span>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" [formControl]="selected">
  </mat-form-field>
  <br>
  <span class="example-input-label"> New tab name: </span>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="name">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value"
               (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
    Contents for {{tab}} tab

    <button mat-raised-button
            class="example-delete-tab-button"
            (click)="removeTab(index)">
      Delete Tab
    </button>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab disabled>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="addTab(name.value)">
            <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Typescript :

```
export class TabGroupDynamicExample {
  tabs = [];
  selected = new FormControl(0);
  name = new FormControl('');

  addTab(tabName) {
    if (!this.tabs.includes(tabName)) {
      this.tabs.push(tabName);
      this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.indexOf(tabName));
    }
  }

  removeTab(index: number) {
    this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
    if (this.tabs.length > 0 && this.selected.value === this.tabs.length) {
      this.selected.setValue(this.selected.value - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-noxuuh?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the tabs array and the actual number of tabs are out of sync.

I modified the addTab method in 3 places:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "tab-group-dynamic-example",
  templateUrl: "tab-group-dynamic-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["tab-group-dynamic-example.css"]
})
export class TabGroupDynamicExample {
  tabs = [];
  selected = new FormControl(-1);
  name = new FormControl("");

  addTab(tabName) {
    this.tabs.push(tabName);
    setTimeout(() => this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.lastIndexOf(tabName)));
  }

  removeTab(index: number) {
    this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
    if (this.tabs.length > 0 && this.selected.value === this.tabs.length) {
      this.selected.setValue(this.selected.value - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Firstly, set the initial value of selected to be -1.

```
 selected = new FormControl(-1);
```

Secondly changed the method to use lastIndexOf, I assume that if a tab with the same name is added you want the newly created one to be selected.

Finally, changed the call for setting the value in a setTimeout. This is to solve the sync issue between the value the component and dom have for tabs.

```
setTimeout(() => this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.lastIndexOf(tabName)));
```